# Do you have a recommendation for a software automating the emailing of a receipt AND a payment instructions file in one go?

Tags: online-payment

I usually create a receipt document by a `receipt-creator-software` and emails it to a customer alongside another document containing payment instructions.

I would like to automate both actions somehow instead doing them manually each time anew (each two different file attachments to a single *email message*);

Some `receipt-creator-software` give an option to email a receipt directly from the software (most likely by sending it from the software company's server) but I have never came across a software which automatically allows *attaching* or *also sending* a second document which contains only details for payment options (such as bank account details for those seeking to pay via a bank transfer).

- FOSS
- Windows and Linux oriented
- The email could be sent from the software developer's servers as one PDF containing the receipt and under it the second file with payment instructions; such as bank account details (and possible ways to do the bank transfer), or some payment-software account details.
- More files could be automatically attached besides a payment instructions file

Do you have a recommendation for a software automating the emailing of a receipt AND a payment instructions file in one go?

Comment: When you think about it you don't want to send out the receipt until **after** they have paid and they can't pay until **after** they have the payment instructions. Are you sure that you don't mean to send out the **invoice** with the payment instructions?

Comment: I never had a case were a customer got a receipt and didn't pay it but if you meant that this could happen than surly I agree; otherwise I didn't understand what you meant to say.

Comment: George, I was trying to say that giving the customer the receipt **before** they have paid, (given that the receipt is their certificate that they **have** paid), is a very poor business practice. I was thinking that maybe you were using the word receipt instead of invoice or bill.